# Sqlite query with concat

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-concat

Help me, please, to make an query. I have a table with two fields - id_text and keywords. How to get a list of texts with different combinations of the same keywords, and a separate field concatenation of these keywords. I understand that somehow need to use group_concat, but I can't understand how to group it. It should look something like this:

```
id_text1       keyword1     keyword1;keyword2 
id_text2       keyword1     keyword1;keyword2 
id_text5       keyword1     keyword1;keyword2 
id_text1       keyword2     keyword1;keyword2 
id_text2       keyword2     keyword1;keyword2 
id_text5       keyword2     keyword1;keyword2
id_text1       keyword3     keyword3;keyword4;keyword5 
id_text3       keyword3     keyword3;keyword4;keyword5 
id_text4       keyword3     keyword3;keyword4;keyword5 
id_text1       keyword4     keyword3;keyword4;keyword5 
id_text3       keyword4     keyword3;keyword4;keyword5 
id_text4       keyword4     keyword3;keyword4;keyword5 
id_text1       keyword5     keyword3;keyword4;keyword5 
id_text3       keyword5     keyword3;keyword4;keyword5 
id_text4       keyword5     keyword3;keyword4;keyword5
```

Comment: What is the source data?

Comment: @CL. the source is Sqlite table with only three columns - id, id_text, keyword

Comment: I did not ask for the columns but for the data.